"Method 'To' of object'_mailItem' failed" error in Outlook Object Model from Excel 2016
I wrote a program in Excel 2016 to send mail.
Cell B16 contains my recipient mail id.
The program shows this error.


"Method 'To' of object'_mailItem' failed"

In this line.

.To = Range("B16")

Also Outlook is changed to Outlook new (this also the one reason for getting this error).
Sub EmailasPDF()
    Dim EApp As Object
    Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim EItem As Object
    Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim invno As Long
    Dim custname As String
    Dim amt As Currency
    Dim dt_issue As Date
    Dim pay_type As String
    Dim ref_no As String
    Dim term As Byte
    Dim path As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim nextrec As Range

    invno = Range("C3")
    custname = Range("B11")
    amt = Range("H42")
    dt_issue = Range("C5")
    pay_type = Range("C6")
    term = Range("C7")
    ref_no = Range("C8")
    path = "C:\YEZLAW INVOICES DATA\PDF format\"
    fname = invno & " - " & custname

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:=path & fname

    Set nextrec = Sheet3.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    nextrec = invno
    nextrec.Offset(0, 1) = custname
    nextrec.Offset(0, 2) = amt
    nextrec.Offset(0, 3) = dt_issue
    nextrec.Offset(0, 4) = dt_issue + term
    nextrec.Offset(0, 6) = pay_type
    nextrec.Offset(0, 9) = ref_no
    nextrec.Offset(0, 10) = Now

    Sheet3.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=nextrec.Offset(0, 7), Address:=path & fname & ".pdf"

    With EItem
        .To = Range("B16")
        .Subject = "Invoice no: " & invno
        .Body = "Please find Invoice attached."
        .Attachments.Add (path & fname & ".pdf")
        .Display
    End With

End Sub

Help me with this  and macro code for this error

What's the value in cell B1 on the ActiveSheet?

Try to change the line
To = Range("B16")

to
To = Range("B16").Text

